# How to recover my invisible HD again?

Tags: macos, mac, partitioning, data-recovery

*I made this several times now, but this time something bad happened.*

### **What I did:**

I installed Windows 7 at a 32GB partition on my slot 2 HD in my MacPro.
Windows 7 made a 105MB partition… I knew this before, but what I didn’t know
was that this partition is now on my slot 4 HD. My home folder, my private
videos and some other stuff are on this 1TB drive.

---

### **What I found out so far:**

I’m currently logged in as another admin since my OS partition as well as the two
other HD's aren't harmed.

### **Disk Utility:**

… only shows the 105MB NTSF partition on this 1TB volume. It isn’t showing my
old 1TB partition/ex-HD named "storehouse". Only the partition tab is telling me
that there now is a 1TB empty free unpartitioned space.

### **Data Rescue II:**

… is showing the Volume as it used to be with it's old Name "storehouse".
A quick scan and a thorough scan both were done in 1 second  which leds me to
the conclusion that there's isn’t something deleted at all (» hope!). Data Rescue
doesn’t even mention the damn "system reserved" partition.

### **Drive Genius:**

… also shows the old partition and doesn’t mention the new one. But looking
at the info it tells me under "content":
FDisk_partition_scheme (instead of Apple_partition_scheme). Well D'oh….

### **Tech Tools:**

… doesn’t show the volume, otherwise I'd might have been
tempted to press rebuild/repair.

---

**What to do next??**
I think the best approach is to buy another 1TB HD and let Disk
Warrior Clone my old one to it… just to be on the safe side.

But what is the best thing to do after this… ???

Comment: Did you look at what `diskutil info` says?  It can sometimes see partitions that Disk Utility can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

Well I knew [iPartition](http://www.coriolis-systems.com/iPartition.php) all along but gladly it came back to my memory after a good nights sleep. Yesterday I tried another hand full of recovery tools, but they where on the wrong battelfield since nothing was deleted. The other product I found was [VolumeWorks](http://subrosasoft.com/OSXSoftware/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=6) but since it couldn’t discover my disk I switched to iPartition. And the money was well invested….

I fired it up, configured the new partition scheme, hit Go. Not a second later all things were back to normal. Now I have an extra backup disk of 1,5TB I also bought yesterday… but hey, it now has a purpose because you could never be to paranoid about updates :)

Answer (score 1):

You should be fine just deleting the reserved partition on the hard drive with whichever tool lets you do that without harming the other partition.

Personally, I would throw the drive into a PC and use something like Acronis Disk Director. In my experience, Mac Software tends to take too much liberty with doing behind-the-scenes stuff.

If you absolutely cannot afford to lose your data, cloning it to another hard drive would definitely be a safe bet.

As for installing Windows 7, I think if you have a partition pre-made and, more importantly, pre-formatted for it, it won't create the reserved partition ([more info](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2009/01/09/how-to-avoid-200mb-hidden-system-partition-from-been-created-during-windows-7-installation/))

Comment: Didn’t work with Acronis Disk Director, because he didn’t let me reboot. So the deletion couldn’t be triggered :(

But it has managed to mess up the Windows 7 installation so that it wouldn’t start.